# android time functions in Delphi Sydney 10.4 - cannot compile- why?

Tags: android, delphi

I am trying to compile the following code (Delphi Sydney 10.4 / Android App), but why does it not compile ?

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}

{$I C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\rtl\posix\android\TimeTypes.inc}
{$I C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\source\rtl\posix\TimeAPI.inc}

function GetNanoTicks:LongWord;
var
  res : timespec;

begin
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, @res);
  Result := res.tv_nsec;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

I get the following error messages from Delphi:

[DCC Error] AHiSysHelperU1.pas(228): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'timespec'
[DCC Error] AHiSysHelperU1.pas(231): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'clock_gettime'
[DCC Error] AHiSysHelperU1.pas(231): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC'
[DCC Error] AHiSysHelperU1.pas(232): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon

I already included the files:
**TimeTypes.inc** and
**TimeAPI.inc**

just as is done in the System unit to implement GetTickCount for Android.

I used the full pathnames to the TimeTypes.inc and TimeAPI.inc because otherwise Delphi cannot find the include files.

After putting full pathnames to those include files in the {$I filename.inc},
Delphi no longer complains about not being able to find the include files.

But still, Delphi refuses to compile, and instead complains about missing declarations of:

Type   timespec
and
procedure clock_gettime.
and
constant CLOCK_MONOTONIC

All of those are declared in the two include files !

So: What is wrong and how to correct this problem ?

Additionally:
Is it possible to correctly refer to the above mentioned two include files,
without using a full pathname ?

Like using a special predefined reference to the Delphi install directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0
?

Comment: Instead of using include directives, you could just add Posix.Time to the uses clause

Comment: @Dave Nottage: Tested and found correct ! But: Why is Delphi not able to find this just by Ctrl-"Left click":ing the problematic identifiers: timespec, clock_gettime and CLOCK_MONOTONIC? In old Delphis (like Delphi 7, from 2002) that works just perfectly - Delphi Sydney unfortunately cannot find the declarations in Posix.Time by ctrl - left clicking those identifiers in system.pas.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the uses -clause --- Problem solved !

```
uses
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows,
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Posix.Pthread,
  Posix.Base, Posix.SysTypes, Posix.Time,
  Posix.SysTime,
{$ENDIF}
  SysUtils, Classes;
```